# How can a JTextArea's properties be updated by an event?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, components, updates

I have made this simple *text editor* program but can't figure out how to change GUI component's properties while the program is *running*. 
Suppose this is a part of my Text Editor's source code:

```
boolean wordwrap = false;

void mainFrame() {
  frame = new JFrame("Text Editor");
  textArea = new JTextArea(50,20);
  textArea.setLineWrap(wordwrap);
```

and let's say I have an event source(`JButton`) added as Listener to change 
`textArea`'s `.setLineWrap(boolean)`. Just like this:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
  if(wordwrap) wordwrap = false;
  else wordwrap = true;
  textArea.setLineWrap(wordwrap);
  frame.repaint();
}
```

But this code is not working!!. So, what is the correct way to update or edit a JAVA GUI component while the program is running ?

Comment: Try `textArea.revalidate()` instead of a repaint on the frame.

Comment: @markspace Well, thanks `.revalidate()` is working just fine!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
revalidate and validate()
```

will update the frame.
You do not need to use repaint().

Final Method:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
  if(wordwrap) wordwrap = false;
  else wordwrap = true;
  textArea.setLineWrap(wordwrap);
  frame.revalidate(); //is preferable but validate() also works.
}
```

You can either update the whole frame or just update the jComponent (insert TextArea instead of "frame".revalidate();)

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI, after I got a chance to test it, it works fine without either the `revalidate()` or the `repaint()`.  I suspect the problem was somewhere else in your code.

```
public class TestTextArea
{
   private final static String testLine = 
           "This is some rather long line that I came up with for testing a textArea.";

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
         public void run()
         {
            gui();
         }
      } );
   }

   private static void gui()
   {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame();

      final JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
      JPanel span = new JPanel();
      JButton toggle = new JButton( "Switch line wrap" );
      toggle.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
      {
         @Override
         public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e )
         {
            textArea.setLineWrap( !textArea.getLineWrap() );
         }
      } );

      for( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
         textArea.append( testLine + testLine + "\n" );
      span.add( toggle );
      frame.add( span, BorderLayout.SOUTH );
      frame.add( textArea );

      frame.pack();
      frame.setSize( 500, 500 );
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
      frame.setVisible( true );
   }
}
```